# Tornado test - access localhost through alternative IP

Tags: python, docker, tornado

I got something really weird going on with Tornado

```python
from tornado.web import Application
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase
import requests
import tornado
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class MyTest(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return Application()

    @tornado.testing.gen_test(timeout=30)
    async def test_pass(self):

        response = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, requests.get,"http://127.0.0.1:" + str(self.get_http_port()) + "/foo")
        print(response)

    @tornado.testing.gen_test(timeout=30)
    async def test_fail(self):
        response = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, requests.get,"http://192.168.2.1:" + str(self.get_http_port()) + "/foo")
        print(response)
```

The first test passes while the second one fails with

```
_____________________________________________________________ MyTest.test_fail _____________________________________________________________

self = <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fea40367e50>

    def _new_conn(self):
        """Establish a socket connection and set nodelay settings on it.
    
        :return: New socket connection.
        """
        extra_kw = {}
        if self.source_address:
            extra_kw["source_address"] = self.source_address
    
        if self.socket_options:
            extra_kw["socket_options"] = self.socket_options
    
        try:
            conn = connection.create_connection(
>               (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
            )

../.virtualenvs/creative-preview/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:170: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

address = ('192.168.2.1', 41809), timeout = None, source_address = None, socket_options = [(6, 1, 1)]

    def create_connection(
        address,
        timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        source_address=None,
        socket_options=None,
    ):
        """Connect to *address* and return the socket object.
    
        Convenience function.  Connect to *address* (a 2-tuple ``(host,
        port)``) and return the socket object.  Passing the optional
        *timeout* parameter will set the timeout on the socket instance
        before attempting to connect.  If no *timeout* is supplied, the
        global default timeout setting returned by :func:`socket.getdefaulttimeout`
        is used.  If *source_address* is set it must be a tuple of (host, port)
        for the socket to bind as a source address before making the connection.
        An host of '' or port 0 tells the OS to use the default.
        """
    
        host, port = address
        if host.startswith("["):
            host = host.strip("[]")
        err = None
    
        # Using the value from allowed_gai_family() in the context of getaddrinfo lets
        # us select whether to work with IPv4 DNS records, IPv6 records, or both.
        # The original create_connection function always returns all records.
        family = allowed_gai_family()
    
        try:
            host.encode("idna")
        except UnicodeError:
            return six.raise_from(
                LocationParseError(u"'%s', label empty or too long" % host), None
            )
    
        for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
            af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
            sock = None
            try:
                sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
    
                # If provided, set socket level options before connecting.
                _set_socket_options(sock, socket_options)
    
                if timeout is not socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT:
                    sock.settimeout(timeout)
                if source_address:
                    sock.bind(source_address)
                sock.connect(sa)
                return sock
    
            except socket.error as e:
                err = e
                if sock is not None:
                    sock.close()
                    sock = None
    
        if err is not None:
>           raise err

../.virtualenvs/creative-preview/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:96: 

...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

self = <my_test.MyTest testMethod=test_fail>

    @tornado.testing.gen_test(timeout=30)
    async def test_fail(self):
>       response = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, requests.get,"http://192.168.2.1:" + str(self.get_http_port()) + "/foo")

my_test.py:18: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py:57: in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
../.virtualenvs/creative-preview/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py:76: in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
../.virtualenvs/creative-preview/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py:61: in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
../.virtualenvs/creative-preview/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:542: in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
../.virtualenvs/creative-preview/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:655: in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x7fea4034dbd0>, request = <PreparedRequest [GET]>, stream = False
timeout = Timeout(connect=None, read=None, total=None), verify = True, cert = None, proxies = OrderedDict()

    def send(self, request, stream=False, timeout=None, verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None):
        """Sends PreparedRequest object. Returns Response object.
    
        :param request: The :class:`PreparedRequest <PreparedRequest>` being sent.
        :param stream: (optional) Whether to stream the request content.
        :param timeout: (optional) How long to wait for the server to send
            data before giving up, as a float, or a :ref:`(connect timeout,
            read timeout) <timeouts>` tuple.
        :type timeout: float or tuple or urllib3 Timeout object
        :param verify: (optional) Either a boolean, in which case it controls whether
            we verify the server's TLS certificate, or a string, in which case it
            must be a path to a CA bundle to use
        :param cert: (optional) Any user-provided SSL certificate to be trusted.
        :param proxies: (optional) The proxies dictionary to apply to the request.
        :rtype: requests.Response
        """
    
        try:
            conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
        except LocationValueError as e:
            raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
    
        self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
        url = self.request_url(request, proxies)
        self.add_headers(request, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
    
        chunked = not (request.body is None or 'Content-Length' in request.headers)
    
        if isinstance(timeout, tuple):
            try:
                connect, read = timeout
                timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=connect, read=read)
            except ValueError as e:
                # this may raise a string formatting error.
                err = ("Invalid timeout {}. Pass a (connect, read) "
                       "timeout tuple, or a single float to set "
                       "both timeouts to the same value".format(timeout))
                raise ValueError(err)
        elif isinstance(timeout, TimeoutSauce):
            pass
        else:
            timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=timeout, read=timeout)
    
        try:
            if not chunked:
                resp = conn.urlopen(
                    method=request.method,
                    url=url,
                    body=request.body,
                    headers=request.headers,
                    redirect=False,
                    assert_same_host=False,
                    preload_content=False,
                    decode_content=False,
                    retries=self.max_retries,
                    timeout=timeout
                )
    
            # Send the request.
            else:
                if hasattr(conn, 'proxy_pool'):
                    conn = conn.proxy_pool
    
                low_conn = conn._get_conn(timeout=DEFAULT_POOL_TIMEOUT)
    
                try:
                    low_conn.putrequest(request.method,
                                        url,
                                        skip_accept_encoding=True)
    
                    for header, value in request.headers.items():
                        low_conn.putheader(header, value)
    
                    low_conn.endheaders()
    
                    for i in request.body:
                        low_conn.send(hex(len(i))[2:].encode('utf-8'))
                        low_conn.send(b'\r\n')
                        low_conn.send(i)
                        low_conn.send(b'\r\n')
                    low_conn.send(b'0\r\n\r\n')
    
                    # Receive the response from the server
                    try:
                        # For Python 2.7, use buffering of HTTP responses
                        r = low_conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
                    except TypeError:
                        # For compatibility with Python 3.3+
                        r = low_conn.getresponse()
    
                    resp = HTTPResponse.from_httplib(
                        r,
                        pool=conn,
                        connection=low_conn,
                        preload_content=False,
                        decode_content=False
                    )
                except:
                    # If we hit any problems here, clean up the connection.
                    # Then, reraise so that we can handle the actual exception.
                    low_conn.close()
                    raise
    
        except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
            raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    
        except MaxRetryError as e:
            if isinstance(e.reason, ConnectTimeoutError):
                # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811
                if not isinstance(e.reason, NewConnectionError):
                    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
    
            if isinstance(e.reason, ResponseError):
                raise RetryError(e, request=request)
    
            if isinstance(e.reason, _ProxyError):
                raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    
            if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
                # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
                raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    
>           raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.2.1', port=41809): Max retries exceeded with url: /foo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fea40367e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

../.virtualenvs/creative-preview/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:516: ConnectionError
==================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.22 seconds ==================================================
```

`192.168.2.1` is localhost as well (through `docker0` interface). The weird thing is that if I run a simple http server `python -m http.server` then `curl 127.0.0.1:8000` and `curl  192.168.2.1:8000` **both** work, so it doesn't seem to be a docker related issue. So I really don't know what's going on

Comment: `localhost` does not refer to the local computer. It's the hostname for `127.0.0.1` and `[::1]` which are the IP addresses of the host on the internal loopback interface. Server can listen to these adresses only.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Still doesn't explain why `curl 192.168.2.1:8000` (or the same with `requests.get` in python) works when the server is run with `python -m http.server`, but not in the second test, which does essentially the same thing.

Comment: can you try `curl -v 192.168.2.1:8000` (verbose) and check the output? maybe you're redirected to localhost and it's not happened in your code. What's your app listening host is? localhost or `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: @ItayB yep, that was it. AsyncHTTPTestCase listens on `127.0.0.1`, not `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @Chrischpo great, I added it as an answer, you can thank me by accepting the answer / upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try curl -v 192.168.2.1:8000 (verbose) and check the output?
maybe you're redirected to localhost and it's not happened in your code.

What's your app listening host is? localhost or 0.0.0.0?

If you want to be able to connect from the local machine you need to ensure you're listening on `0.0.0.0`.